# ARRAYFORMULA with SUM, IF and AND

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

I have a table like this:

```
☑   667     No
☐   667     No
☑   667     Yes
```

and want to sum the numbers when the checkbox is checked and the state is `YES`.

I tried something like this,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(AND(A2:A<>"☐",C1:C="Yes"),B1:B)))
```

but it is not working.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=sumifs(B:B,A:A,"☑",C:C,"YES")
```